# How do you disable S3 Object Logging to Cloud Trail using AWS CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to disable the object level logging to cloud trail through cli command? is there any commands to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

There is [put-event-selectors](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudtrail/put-event-selectors.html):

> Configures an event selector for your trail. Use event selectors to further specify the management and data event settings for your trail.

Using the command you can modify `DataResources` for your trial.

Comment: yeah is there command 

aws cloudtrail put-event-selectors --trail-name TrailName --event-selectors '[{"ReadWriteType": "All","IncludeManagementEvents": true,"DataResources": [{"Type":"AWS::S3::Object", "Values": ["arn:aws:s3:::mybucket1/","arn:aws:s3:::mybucket2/"]}]}]' 
like this to disable